# Elasticsearch Apm Error Source Code Problem

Tags: elasticsearch, apm

Now I'm using Elasticsearch APM, I find when some error occurred in python project, the source code in the exception stack can be collected, After reading the APM python agent source code, I find the apm agent will read the py file and find the source code around the exception line, so we can see the python source code in kibana
[image]

But in java project, I find the java agent only collects exception stack, no source code, is it because decompile java class to java file expensive?

[image]